# fail to focus on page load

Tags: javascript, focus, pageload

I can focus on the text input when I click the button but it doesn't focus on the text input when page first loaded even though I am using the same function. How can I focus at the input textfield once the page is loaded ?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/derwi

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

function generate_question (){
    var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10),
    num2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);

    $('.result').hide();
    $('.left').html(num1 + ' x ' + num2 + ' = <input type="text" size="3" class="answer">');
    $('.answer').val('');
    $('.answer').focus();

    $('.answer').keypress(function(e){
        if (e.which == 13) {
            if ($(this).val() == num1 * num2) {
                $('.result').html('Very Good!');
                $('.result').show();
            } else {
                $('.result').html('Try Again');
                $('.result').show();
            }
        }
    })
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    generate_question();
    $('#again').click(function(){
        generate_question();
    });
    $('#again').keypress(function(e){
        if (e.which == 32){
            generate_question();
        }
    });
})
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="content">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="result"></div>
</div>

<div class="instruction">
    Hit enter to check your answer. 
    <button type='button' id='again' style='margin-top: 10px;'>Do another one?</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works for me in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('.answer').focus();` in your ready function

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('.answer').focus();
});
```

DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/EX0xS9d8o3TqUqiEOAL5?p=preview

Comment: I tried this. It doesn't focus the textfield when the page first loaded.
DEMO: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/derwi?editors=101

Comment: I tried using another browser but still can't get the focus on load. But then I tried another computer opening the same page, it works.

Comment: seems like a browser version issue. Cant be sure without more info.